# Proxy not rejecting illegal host header when coming from my VM provider's network

Tags: http, nginx, header, django

I have a django app hosted on a linode VM, proxied by nginx on that same VM.

In my nginx config I have a block to [deny bad host header requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477436/3790954):

```
## Deny illegal Host headers
if ($host !~* ^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

This blocks almost all the bad requests, but I'm still getting occasional requests from a random linode host (the app sends me an email due to this host not being in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` whitelist). Why are those requests able to get past nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$host` will be set to `$server_name` if the client does not provide a Host header value in the request. You should use `$http_host` to access the pure Host header.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for details.